# How to handle an exception when it is catched in a another module

Tags: python, exception

Is their a way to prevent the module urllib3 from catching a KeyboardInterrupt?
I need to perform some process when a KeyboardInterrupt occurs, but the problem is that the urllib3 module seems to catch the exception without passing it on.

I wrote an example script to demonstrate my problem.

*connector.py*

```
import requests
from time import sleep

class Connector:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connect(self):
        try:
            URL="https://www.gelbeseiten.de"
            print("Connecting")
            sleep(1)
            print("Now")
            requests.get(URL)
            requests.get(URL)
            requests.get(URL)
            requests.get(URL)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception in connect")
            raise Exception()
```

*main.py*

```
import connector

def main():
    try:
        conn=connector.Connector()
        conn.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception in main")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the script is performing the GET requests, i perform a KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl + C) and what i would expect is that first "Exception in connect" and then "Exception in main" is printed but instead i get following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/test/main.py", line 6, in main
    conn.connect()
  File "/tmp/test/connector.py", line 16, in connect
    requests.get(URL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 428, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 747, in close
    v.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 325, in close
    self.poolmanager.clear()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 222, in clear
    self.pools.clear()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 100, in clear
    self.dispose_func(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 173, in <lambda>
    self.pools = RecentlyUsedContainer(num_pools, dispose_func=lambda p: p.close())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 491, in close
    if conn:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Which indicates that the module urllib3 got the interrupt signal and did not pass it on to my exceptions handlers. Is their a way to get my expected behavior?

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` isn't an `Exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyboardInterrupt` will not be catched.

> exception KeyboardInterrupt
> Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally Control-C or Delete). During execution, a check for interrupts is made regularly. The exception inherits from BaseException so as to not be accidentally caught by code that catches Exception and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting.

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `KeyboardInterrupt` is not a subclass of `Exception`. If you specifically want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, you have to use `except KeyboardInterrupt as e:`.

Also, it is better to use `raise e` instead of raising a new `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your `raise` script as `KeyboardInterrupt` seems not like inherited from `Exception`. Instead, it's from `BaseException`.
Please try the following code for your `connector.py`.

```
import requests
from time import sleep

class Connector:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connect(self):
        try:
            URL="https://www.gelbeseiten.de"
            print("Connecting")
            sleep(1)
            print("Now")
            requests.get(URL)
            requests.get(URL)
            requests.get(URL)
            requests.get(URL)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception in connect")
            raise Exception()
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print("Keyboard interrupt")
            raise Exception
```

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i was looking for. I think my question is answered now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks for the kindly remind. I'm new to stackoverflow and feel sorry if this causes extra difficulty for understanding.